# Create Virtual subdomain on the fly using UrlRewriter.net in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to create virtual subdomain with UrlRewriter.net.

Can anyone please help me with, how can i create virtual subdomain on the fly using urlrewriter.net

Example: Blogger website generates blogname.blogspot.com   I would like to do something similar.

If that is not possible with URLRewriter than can anyone help me that how to create list of virtual domains (example I have 2 subdomains) which have same site structure as maindomain but it would render different data based on subdomain it is trying to access.

Example:

furniture.abc.com

electronics.abc.com

Few other points:  I am doing all this stuff in shared hosting and don't have access to IIS